# Number theory, proving or finding counterexample.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or find a counterexample: The product of any three consecutive natural numbers is divisible by 6.

Answer

True, because product of three consecutive natural numbers can be divisible by 6. Thus, $(n)\dot{}(n+1)\dot{}(n+2) | 6$

Can i get a feedback for this answer.

Comment: Just use induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of the $3$ consecutive numbers must be divisible by $2$. At least one (in fact, exactly one) of them must also be divisible by $3$.

If you want to be rigorous, write down the three natural numbers as $3n, 3n+1, 3n+2$ and show that at least one of them must be $0$ modulo $2$, and at least one of them must be $0$ modulo $3$.

Since both $2$ and $3$ divides the product, $2\cdot3=6$ must divide it as well.

Comment: And this is a real proof, instead of restating the question